# X won't start (black screen after splash)

Tags: xorg

When I boot my computer, the purple Ubuntu splash appears (without the orange dots) for a split second, and then the screen turns black. I was able to get the `Xorg.0.log` from the command line. I think this happened after installing the proprietary drivers for my Radeon HD 6770.

[`Xorg.0.log` file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=e4Ry4Ndv) (Sorry, file is too big)

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

The key here is line 589 onward:

```
incompatible kernel module detected - HW accelerated OpenGL will not work
```

Right now, the X server in the repos does not work well with any fglrx driver in the repos. So do the following steps:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot to see the Grub menu.
2. Go to "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" using the down-arrow key and then scroll down once to the first Recovery Mode kernel option.
3. Go down to the option that says "enable networking" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Go down to the option that says "root shell prompt" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Very carefully type the following commands (for the long filename try just typing `amd` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>):

   ```
   apt-get -y install build-essential
   mkdir fglrx
   cd fglrx
   wget --referer='http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86' http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-catalyst-13.11-betaV9.95-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
   unzip amd-catalyst-13.11-betaV9.95-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
   chmod a+x amd-catalyst-13.11-betaV9.95-linux-x86.x86_64.run
   ./amd-catalyst-13.11-betaV9.95-linux-x86.x86_64.run
   ```

You will be prompted to agree to a license agreement. Do not build the distribution-specific driver package when given the option. Go with the "Standard" or non-"Expert" install type. <kbd>Enter</kbd> through all the other options. Wait until you are allowed to return to the prompt and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to reboot.

Answer (score -1):

try to login with your account in a terminal then use this command "startx".